# Find minimum of Archimedean spiral in revolution

Tags: polar-coordinates

I just recently asked about limacon curves, but now I want to examine the Archimedian curve:

$$r=a + b\theta$$

The question is essentially the same, for a given range, how would one find the minimum $x$-value in a particular revolution. Take $r=1 - \frac{0.5}{2\pi}\theta$ for $0\le\theta<360$:

Ignore the fact that the picture goes to $3\pi$.

[image]

It is very slight and hard to tell, but our smallest $x$ value is NOT at $\theta=180$. But where is it? Obviously it is less that $180$, but how do I get that angle/point? I have already tried differentiating my function, but it does not work out to be a nice solve.

Comment: Is there a reason you have not accepted an answer to your limacon question?  http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Lagrange multiplier approach:

We are trying to minimize $f(r,\theta) = r \cos \theta$ subject to the constraint $g(r,\theta) = r - b\,\theta = a$.

We calculate
$$
\nabla f = (\cos \theta,-r\sin \theta)\\
\nabla g = (1,-b)
$$
So, setting $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ and $g(r,\theta) = a$, we have the system of equations
$$
\cos \theta = \lambda\\
-r \sin \theta = -b \lambda\\
r - b \theta = a
$$
Any $(r,\theta)$ solving the above system will be a local minimum or a local maximum for the $x$-coordinate.

---

Attempted solution: substituting $\lambda = \cos \theta$, the second equation yields
$$
-r \sin \theta = -b \cos \theta \implies r = b\cot \theta
$$
From there, we may make the final equation an equation on $\theta$ alone:
$$
b \cot \theta - b\theta = a \implies\\
\cot \theta - \theta = \frac ab
$$
This equation cannot be solved directly with any commonly used algebraic methods, but solutions can easily be found via numerical methods.

---

**NOTE:** *I seem to have chosen the wrong critical point below.  I will correct it if I can.  Ignore for now.*

For the example you've provided, $a = 1$, and $b = -1/(4 \pi)$.  According to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cot+x+%2B+x+%3D+4+pi), the third positive critical value of $\theta$ (i.e. the one you want) is
$$
\theta \approx 6.12907243518723 \approx (0.975)(2 \pi)
$$

Comment: your second constraint, should it be -r*sin(theta)

Comment: Fixed.  This should be right now.